# How to calculate the probability of the next value in a Random Sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random

Assuming that $X$ is the next value in a finite length random sequence, e.g.
$$
abbcccaaccbacccabbacababaccccbacabcbacacX
$$what would be the $2$-letter most likely to correspond to the value of $X$

1. ($a$ and $b$)
2. ($a$ and $c$)
3. ($b$ and $c$)

What I'm looking for is a formula with which to meet the $2$ letters that are more likely to be the next letter in the sequence

Comment: Is there an independence assumption among the digits?  I.e. is the second digit independent of the value of the first digit?

Comment: Not a lot of information here.  If you assume (well, "guess" really) that each letter is chosen independently with some fixed probabilities then you can use the observed frequency to estimate those three probabilities.  $b$ is seen the least, so if you had to guess this way I suppose you'd guess that either $a$ or $c$ was more likely to be observed next.

Comment: the point in my sequece is that is random it means that there is no pattern to fallow, so is there any forumula to detect what pattern is about to break, if a pattern predict for example a B and I can dectect it is almost breaking pattern then next values could be A or C, is there a any option to decect it?

Answer (score 3):

It would really help to know something about the process that generated the sequence. There are many possibilities, but here are two ways to look at it:

If we assume each letter appears independently of any other, so that this is just a sequence of draws from a simple probability distribution, then we can estimate the probabilities based on the frequency of each letter occurring.

$fr(a) = 13 \\
fr(b) = 10 \\
fr(c) = 17$

Dividing those frequencies by the total number of letters, 40, gives us the estimated probabilities:

$Pr(a) = \frac{13}{40} = 0.325 \\
Pr(b) = \frac{10}{40} = 0.25 \\
Pr(c) = \frac{17}{40} = 0.425$

Then, since the probabilities of each letter are independent, we can see that:

$Pr(ab) = Pr(a)Pr(b) = 0.08125 \\
Pr(ac) = Pr(a)Pr(c) = 0.138125 \\
Pr(bc) = Pr(b)Pr(c) = 0.10625$

This is assuming that the letters appear in that order, if order doesn't matter, double each of those probabilities. Then of these options, "ac" is the most likely, followed by "bc", with "ab" the least. The probabilities don't add to 1 because there are three possibilities missed - those of one letter appearing doubled.

Alternatively, we could assume that this is generated by a nice simple Markov chain model where the probability of a given letter depends only on the letter before it. We can estimate those probabilities based on how often a given letter appears after another one. In that case, we have (using the shorthand of $Pr(X|Y)$ meaning the probability that X appears given that the last letter was Y):

$Pr(a|a) = 0.0769 \\
Pr(b|a) = 0.3846 \\
Pr(c|a) = 0.5385 \\
Pr(a|b) = 0.6 \\
Pr(b|b) = 0.2 \\
Pr(c|b) = 0.2 \\
Pr(a|c) = 0.3125 \\
Pr(b|c) = 0.1875 \\
Pr(c|c) = 0.5$

So this time, using the fact that we're running off a previous "c", let's look at the probabilities of the various combinations working off the fact that $Pr(XY|Z) = Pr(X|Z)Pr(Y|X)$:

$\begin{array}{l l l}
Pr(aa|c) = 0.024 & Pr(ab|c) = 0.120 & Pr(ac|c) = 0.168 \\
Pr(ba|c) = 0.113 & Pr(bb|c) = 0.038 & Pr(bc|c) = 0.038 \\
Pr(ca|c) = 0.156 & Pr(cb|c) = 0.094 & Pr(cc|c) = 0.250
\end{array}$

If we collapse the probabilities for ab & ba, and so forth, we get:

$Pr(ab) = 0.233 \\
Pr(ac) = 0.324 \\
Pr(bc) = 0.132$

So again, ac is more likely than ab, which is more likely than ac, although the specific probabilities did change a little.

That said, the transition probabilities were calculated on not much data, and you definitely wouldn't want to try to infer some more complicated Markov process based on the small length of the sequence. Even what I've put here has a pretty big margin of error involved.

Comment: the point in my sequece is that is random it means that there is no pattern to fallow, so is there any forumula to detect what pattern is about to break, if a pattern predict for example a B and I can dectect it is almost breaking pattern then next values could be A or C, is there a any option to decect it?

Comment: If the pattern is truly random, and each letter appears with equal probability and without regards to what comes before it, then no, you can't predict what will come next by definition and to think otherwise is essentially the Gambler's Fallacy. It's like saying "If I flip a fair coin fifty times and get HTTHTTHTTHHHTHTHHTH...TTH, how can I predict what the next flip will be?"

However, if you have *any* suspicion that there is an underlying model, then something like my approach can help you try to understand what that model might be and how it affects the next terms in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that b never follows ac. Therefore, I would think that b would be the least likely to follow ac.

Comment: the sequence above is just an example, I need help with a formula that can be applied to any sequences.